# R find row identificators of matrix given an element value of a specific column

Tags: r

In the following csv

```
id,T1,T2,T3,T4,T5
1001,28,3,40,15,200
1002,28,3,80,6,4
1003,2,3,,6,12
1004,60,3,6,,26
1005,2,5,6,8,
1006,28,2,4,8,12
1007,25,3,5,7,9
```

I'm trying  to find the list of **id** of a given column value, for example the list of id for **T1=28** is [1001, 1002, 1006]
I'm trying to use the `factors` function but can't find the way

Comment: You should use `which` : `df[which(df[,2]==28),1]`

Comment: WOW that was fast! thanks which(N$T1 == 28)